# java.lang.ClassCastException using generics with mergeSort

Tags: java, generics, mergesort, classcastexception, comparable

I got the following exception in my code:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer; at the following method:

```
public static void comprobar() {
    Integer a1[] = crearAleatorioInteger(100000);
    Integer a2[] = Arrays.copyOf(a1, a1.length);
    Ordenacion.quickSort(a1);
    a2 = Ordenacion.mergeSort2(a2); //Here is where the exception is thrown
    if(Ordenacion.sonIguales(a1,a2)) System.out.println("Bien");
    else System.out.println("Mal");
}
```

I guess the mistake must be in the method `mergeSort2()` which is in the class `Ordenacion`, it is the following:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort2(T[] v) {
    return mergeSort2(v, 0, v.length - 1);
}
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort2(T[] v, int i, int f){
    if (f - i <= 1) {
        T[] res = (T[]) new Comparable[f-i+1];
        if(f==i) res[0] = v[i];
        else if (v[i].compareTo(v[f]) > 0){
            res[0] = v[f];
            res[1] = v[i];
        }
        else{
            res[0] = v[f];
            res[1] = v[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    else{
        int m = (i + f) / 2;
        return merge2(mergeSort2(v, i, m),mergeSort2(v, m + 1, f));
    }
}
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] merge2(T[] v1, T[] v2){
    int a = 0, b = 0, k = 0;
    T[] res = (T[]) new Comparable[v1.length+v2.length];
    while(a < v1.length && b < v2.length){
        if (v1[a].compareTo(v2[b]) < 0) res[k++] = v1[a++];
        else res[k++] = v2[b++];
    }
    while (a < v1.length) res[k++] = v1[a++];
    while (b < v2.length) res[k++] = v2[b++];
    return res;
}
```

Thank you for any help you may offer

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the wrong array type and casting it to a "T[]" here...

```
T[] res = (T[]) new Comparable[f-i+1];
```

You need to create an array of type T which is not that straightforward.

As there is no way to find out the actual type of a generic type variable at runtime, you might have to do something like this...

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort2(T[] v, Class<T> type) {
    return mergeSort2(v, 0, v.length - 1, type);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort2(T[] v, int i, int f, Class<T> type){
    if (f - i <= 1) {
        T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, f-i+1);
        ...
```

UPDATE:

As @pbabcdefp pointed out, you don;t need to pass around the "Class" parameter. You can use this instead...

```
        T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(v.getClass().getComponentType(), f-i+1);
```

This only works for arrays, if you had a List, you won't be able to get the type...

Comment: In this case you don't need to pass a `Class<T>` as you can use `v.getClass().getComponentType()`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - true, I forgot that this works for Arrays (and I even answered a question like this earlier!!)

Comment: It now says "cannot find symbol - method newInstance(java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?>, int)

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN - You are importing the "right" Array right? java.lang.reflect.Array

Comment: Thank u so much, now it works. Though it doesn't give me the right answer at leasts there are no exceptions hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You create an array of `Comparable` here:

```
T[] res = (T[]) new Comparable[f-i+1];
```

and try to cast it to `Integer[]`. Which is obviously wrong, since `Comparable` is no subclass of `Integer` and thus the cast cannot be performed. You'll have to create a new array of type `T`.

Comment: "*You'll have to create a new array of type `T`*" and how can we do that?

Comment: That is not the line that throws the exception.

Comment: What @pbabcdefp means is that at runtime generics will be erased so `T[] res = (T[]) new Comparable[f-i+1];` where `<T extends Comparable<T>>` is equivalent of `Comparable[] res = (Comparable[]) new Comparable[f-i+1];` which means that it can't throw this exception. Problem OP is having is here `a2 = Ordenacion.mergeSort2(a2);` where we are trying to assign `Comparable[]` to `Integer[]`. Solution to this problem is in fact creation of array of `T` type, but `new T[]` is not valid (because of type erasure) so it would be good to add in your answer proper solution of this problem.

Comment: @pbabcdefp this **is** where the exception is thrown. op just didn't post the full stacktrace but the least important part of it. @Pshemo `(T[]) Arrays.newInstance(Class<T> , int)' could create a 'T[]' downside: you need to provide the class of 'T'.